# Static pages not being allowed

Tags: php, static-website

I followed [the directions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) for creating a static front page and displaying the news on another page. I have done this before with success but now I am having a problem.

When I go to mysite.com/news I am getting an Internal Server Error, but when I undo the static pages options, everything is fine.

What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: Hello please provide details information so we can identify the problem.

Comment: Please share the code of `front-page.php`. You can use [pastebin.com](http://www.pastebin.com) for sharing the code.

Comment: here is the front page file http://pastebin.com/FQa3bJjp

Answer (score 0):

There are many things to check for. It sounds like you are not doing anything 'complex' so I'd start by looking at the theme you are using to see if it has its own custom settings for 'front page' type features.

Maybe those are getting in the way?

Sorry, without any more detailed information, it's hard to tell.

Comment: The theme does not have a front page option